# VirtualBox bridged network No Internet in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am having windows 10 Host and virtual box 6.0.1 latest.
problem:

scenario 1:

I configured virtualbox bridged network adapter and i installed 3 Ubuntu 18.04.1(dhcp enabled) all VMs are getting same IP address and not able to ping goole.com(or any website) No Internet

scenario 2:

I set static IP address all the VMs are able to ping each other and even i am able to ssh using putty on host machine.
but NO Internet

Ping command's O/P:

@localhost:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com(bom07s18-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4009:80c::200e)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
24 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 23522ms

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First create host network manager adapter and then  enable the two Network Adapter settings in Guest Machine (Adapter 1 - NAT & Adapter 2 - Host only Adapter).

You cannot update the network settings when the guest is running, kindly shutdown and do the changes.

http://christophermaier.name/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox/